# Show the Size of the boxes in treemaps (squarify)

Tags: python, treemap

I'm using the python library squarify 
to plot a treemap:

The basic plot is fine for my use case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import squarify  
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'nb_people':[8,3,4,2], 'group':["group A", "group B", "group C", "group D"] }) 
squarify.plot(sizes=df['nb_people'], label=df['group'], alpha=.8 ) 
plt.axis('off') 
plt.show()
```

[image]

But I would like to add the size of the box along with the name.
Is there an option for that?

Comment: Perhaps you can just append the size (as a string) to the name?

Comment: @ErtySeidohl yeah, did that. Just wonder if there is a parameter for it

Answer (score -1):

you can just add fig.set_size_inches above squarify.plot

Comment: This doesn't show the size of the single square in the treemap